# Removing items from list of dictionaries and appending them back

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Suppose we have a list of dictionaries:

`[{0: [0, 1, 2, 3], 1: [4]}, {2: [5, 6, 7, 8], 3: [9]}, {4: [10, 11, 12]}]`

and we wish to split the dictionaries in this list according to some tuple for example `(0, 5, 10)` such that for each ith value in the tuple, if this value is present in any innermost sublist of the ith dictionary it gets split into its own list. In addition, the dictionaries are renumbered continuously from 0. Thus the output of the above would be.

`[{0:[0], 1: [1, 2, 3], 2: [4]}, {3:[5], 4: [6, 7, 8], 5: [9]}, {6:[10], 7: [11, 12]}]`

since `0` is a part of the first dictionary, it would get split. Since `5` is a part of the second dictionary, it would get split. Similarly, since `10` is the 3rd value in the tuple, and it is a part of the third dictionary it would get split.

I have written the following code:

```
for i in range(0, len(newlist)):
    for key, value in newlist[i].items():
        if x[i] in value:
            value.remove(x[i])
        newlist[i][key].append(x[i])
```

This produces `[{0: [1, 2, 3, 0], 1: [4, 0]}, {2: [6, 7, 8, 5], 3: [9, 5]}, {4: [11, 12, 10]}]` which is not the desired output, it appends to each list for the key.

How do I add just as a single list as in the desired output and how do I renumber the lists as desired using list comprehension or otherwise?

Comment: why `0:[0], 1: [0, 1, 2, 3]` instead of `0:[0], 1: [1, 2, 3]`?

Comment: @recnac I have fixed that typo

Comment: I think your requirement is unclear: 1. you change the `key` of `dict` when split, but `dict` is stored unorder. 2. if a list is [3, 4, 5, 6, 7], how does this split? three parts [3, 4] [5] [6, 7] or [3, 4, 5], [6, 7]?

Comment: As [3,4] [5] [6,7]

Comment: @recnac Yes it is stored as unordered dict

Comment: another question, are there several split numbers in one list, like: `[0, 1, 2, 5, 6]`, both 0, 5 to split?

Comment: @recnac That can't happen right, because the first value of the tuple is to be deleted from the first dictionary only

Comment: I was able to get a bigger combined dictionary according to your needs @kauray, Does that help you?

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh That provides the correct solution, however is that the most efficient?

Comment: Lets talk on the comment section of the question @kauray ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use a unified index `idx` to track the current key number in `dict`, and collect all the components splitted, and merge them into a new `dict`.
I have edit your example input to show more complex situation.

```
newlist = [{0: [0, 1, 2], 1: [3]}, {2: [4, 5, 6, 7, 8], 3: [9]}, {4: [10], 5:[11, 12]}]
x = [0, 5, 10]

for l in newlist:
    components = []
    for key, value in sorted(l.items()):  # sort items because the storage of dict is unordered
        for split_val in x:
            if split_val in value:  # split the list if in value
                index = value.index(split_val)
                components += [value[:index], [split_val], value[index + 1:]]
                break
        else:
            components.append(value)

    cur_dict = {}
    for component in components:
        if component:   # only add non-empty component
            cur_dict[idx] = component
            idx += 1
    result.append(cur_dict)
```

output:

```
[{0: [0], 1: [1, 2], 2: [3]}, {3: [4], 4: [5], 5: [6, 7, 8], 6: [9]}, {7: [10], 8: [11, 12]}]
```

Comment: This doesn't match the expected output?

Comment: I have edited the input example to show more complex situation, like split number is not the first number @DeveshKumarSingh

Comment: thanks, but it does not support multiple split numbers, which I have confirmed with you, like `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]` @kauray

Comment: @recnac that will not be required

Answer (score 2):

I was able to obtain a combined dictionary using the following logic

```
li = [{0: [0, 1, 2, 3], 1: [4]}, {2: [5, 6, 7, 8], 3: [9]}, {4: [10, 11, 12]}]

values_list =  []
#Iterate through values of all dictionaries and join them end to end
for dct in li:
    values_list.extend(dct.values())

print(values_list)
#[[0, 1, 2, 3], [4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9], [10, 11, 12]]
dct = {}
idx = 0

#Iterate through the list
for item in values_list:
    #If we have more then one item in the list, idx goes to first item, idx+1 goes to rest, idx gets incremented by 2
    if len(item) > 1:
        dct[idx] = [item[0]]
        dct[idx+1] = item[1:]
        idx+=2
    # If we have one item in the list, idx goes to first item, idx gets incremented by 1
    else:
        dct[idx] = [item[0]]
        idx+=1

print(dct)
#{0: [0], 1: [1, 2, 3], 2: [4], 3: [5], 4: [6, 7, 8], 5: [9], 6: [10], 7: [11, 12]}
```

Comment: three problems here, 1. OP want remain sperate dict format in output, 2. `values_list.extend(dct.values())` may cause unorder add, should sort first 3. split number maybe not the first element I think

Comment: How would you define `efficient` @kauray? Do you mean compact in readability? Or efficiency in terms of runtime?

Comment: @recnac The sublist of values are already sorted as you can see, no need to run an extra sort, about the separate dict format, The OP says it provides the correct solution for him!

Comment: @recnac the output is correct but not as expected in the format

Comment: So the only problem is to divide it into a list of dictionaries @kauray ?

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh it provide the correct solution, not the format , efficiency would be runtime

Comment: The Format should be as mentioned in the original question, your solution is correct not the format

Comment: Is an assumption that the tuple elements will always be in the first element of any sublist? e.g 5 is first in `[5,6,7,8]`, 10 is first in `[10,11,12]` correct?

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh No, it could be any element

Comment: Got it, that could be a new processing on the combined list we get, in order of efficiency, getting the combined dict is being done in O(N), where N is the total number of elements in the sublists of dictionaries in the list, we cannot do better than that! @kauray Or maybe it can be a new question entirely on dividing a combined list into sublists according to indexing on values!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192942/discussion-between-devesh-kumar-singh-and-kauray).